# Can I turn off weekly screentime reports while still keeping screentime and other screentime notifications on?

Tags: notifications, screen-time

I'd like to get rid of the weekly screen time report notification. It's merely a weekly distraction. If I need it, I'll go to the screen time app and find it there. Disabling screen time notifications also does not appear an option to me because children might ask for more time and I don't want to miss those requests.

Comment: I disabled screentime for my devices after it prevented me from erasing a phone (I'm 100% I entered the correct passcode). Although it might look like disabling for yourself will also disable screentime for children, it does not.

Comment: Afaik, there's no way to do this without disabling notifications or disabling Screen Time altogether...

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the weekly notifications by long pressing the notification (when it appears), then tap the elipsis (3 dots) in the upper right hand corner of the notification, then select “Turn Off.”

[image]
[image]

This turns off the weekly screening report on iOS and iPadOS; it **does not** turn off Screen Time itself.

Alternatively, you can go into the *Settings app →  Notifications →  Screen Time -> turning Notifications to ”Off”*.